# Замена подстроки в строке JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. У меня есть пару селектов. в результате выбора значений каждого селекта составляется строка такого типа:

```
var string = Имя выбранного селекта = значение (option value)&Имя выбранного селекта = значение (option value)&.....
```

и так до конца. мне надо чтобы при смене значения селекта который я уже выбирал ранее значение в этой строке находилось и менялось, а у меня при выборе оно вставляется в конец строки, и получется что 1 и тот же параметр может вывестись 2 раза.

Как можно создать регулярное выражение которое ищет и заменяет нужное значение?

Код проверки:

```
var allparams = "";
var selname = "";
var selval = "";

if($("#reg option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#reg').attr('name');
    selval = $("#reg option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#mode option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#mode').attr('name');
    selval = $("#mode option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#redir option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#redir').attr('name');
    selval = $("#redir option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#tic option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#tic').attr('name');
    selval = $("#tic option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#yaca option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#yaca').attr('name');
    selval = $("#yaca option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#trust option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#trust').attr('name');
    selval = $("#trust option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#vozr-mes option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#vozr-mes').attr('name');
    selval = $("#vozr-mes option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#pub option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#pub').attr('name');
    selval = $("#pub option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#indeks-pub option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#indeks-pub').attr('name');
    selval = $("#indeks-pub option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#pub_len0 option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#pub_len0').attr('name');
    selval = $("#pub_len0 option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#pub_month option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#pub_month').attr('name');
    selval = $("#pub_month option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#pub_a option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#pub_a').attr('name');
    selval = $("#pub_a option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#spama option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#spama').attr('name');
    selval = $("#spama option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#v-arhive option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#v-arhive').attr('name');
    selval = $("#v-arhive option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#spama option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#spama').attr('name');
    selval = $("#spama option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#mozhno-v-arhiv option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#mozhno-v-arhiv').attr('name');
    selval = $("#mozhno-v-arhiv option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#dobavit option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#dobavit').attr('name');
    selval = $("#dobavit option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#ggl option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#ggl').attr('name');
    selval = $("#ggl option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#rota option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#rota').attr('name');
    selval = $("#rota option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#mira option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#mira').attr('name');
    selval = $("#mira option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#weba option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#weba').attr('name');
    selval = $("#weba option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#sum option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#sum').attr('name');
    selval = $("#sum option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#seven option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#seven').attr('name');
    selval = $("#seven option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#v-sape option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#v-sape').attr('name');
    selval = $("#v-sape option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#status option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#status').attr('name');
    selval = $("#status option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#kod-otv option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#kod-otv').attr('name');
    selval = $("#kod-otv option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#inggl option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#inggl').attr('name');
    selval = $("#inggl option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#reyting option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#reyting').attr('name');
    selval = $("#reyting option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#monetizaciyarub option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#monetizaciyarub').attr('name');
    selval = $("#monetizaciyarub option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#monetizacii option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#monetizacii').attr('name');
    selval = $("#monetizacii option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#roi option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#roi').attr('name');
    selval = $("#roi option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#rashody-rub-v-god option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#rashody-rub-v-god').attr('name');
    selval = $("#rashody-rub-v-god option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#esche-podkl option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#esche-podkl').attr('name');
    selval = $("#esche-podkl option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#mozhno-kleit option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#mozhno-kleit').attr('name');
    selval = $("#mozhno-kleit option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#subj option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#subj').attr('name');
    selval = $("#subj option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#alexa option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#alexa').attr('name');
    selval = $("#alexa option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#trafik-iz-ps option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#trafik-iz-ps').attr('name');
    selval = $("#trafik-iz-ps option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#dvizhok option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#dvizhok').attr('name');
    selval = $("#dvizhok option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}
if($("#dney option:selected").val() != ""){
    selname = $('#dney').attr('name');
    selval = $("#dney option:selected").val();
    allparams += selname + "=" + selval + "&";
}


var params = "";
var selectname = "";
var selectval = "";


$("select").on("change",function(){




    selectname += $(this).attr('name');


    selectval +=  $(this).val();

    if(allparams !== ""){
        if(params !== ""){
            params+="&" + selectname + "=" + selectval;
        }
        else{
            if(allparams.indexOf($(this).attr('name')) == - 1){
                params+=allparams + selectname + "=" + selectval;
            }
            else{
                params+= allparams + selectname + "=" + selectval;
                console.log('b');
            }

        }
    }
    else{
        if(params !== ""){
            params+= "&" + selectname + "=" + selectval;
        }
        else{
            params+= selectname + "=" + selectval;
        }
    }

    console.log(params);

    //indow.location = "http://nature-photographing.com/video/test/select.php?" + params;


});

function setOpt(a,b){

}
```

Comment: Можете приатачить весь пример вашего кода ?

Comment: код вставлен) достаточно большой поэтому не хотел вставлять

Comment: зачем вы делаете строку, с которой потом работать не умеете, Собирайте в массив

Comment: потому что нужна именно строка, а не массив. эта страка добавляется к концу сайта как GET параметры и происходит переадресация на данный сайт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю все селекторы хранить в объекте, и строчку формировать на основе объекта. При этом регулярные выражения вообще можно не использовать.

```
var allparams = {};

if($("#esche-podkl option:selected").val() != ""){
   selname = $('#esche-podkl').attr('name');
   selval = $("#esche-podkl option:selected").val();
   allparams[selname] = selval;
}
if($("#mozhno-kleit option:selected").val() != ""){
   selname = $('#mozhno-kleit').attr('name');
   selval = $("#mozhno-kleit option:selected").val();
   allparams[selname] = selval;
}
// ваши if-ы дальше

var str = "";
for(var sel in allparams) {
   str += sel+"="+allparams[sel]+"&";
}
```

Алгоритм такой, сначала все ваши if-ы собирают объект.
После за один проход из этого объекта собирается строчка.

Comment: Можете показать пример кода? допустим 3 селекта. как это можно сделать

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov привёл пример кода

Comment: хорошо, строчку составил. а как проверять и нужное значение менять в строке теперь?

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov а что вы хотите проверить? в данном примере оно будет автоматически перезаписываться по последнем использованию, безо всяких проверок

Comment: `allSelectors["selector2"]` автоматически перезапишет старый `allSelectors["selector2"]`

Comment: мне надо чтобы после всего этого когда строчка уже сформировалась, если я хочу поменять значение селекта на другое, он его в этой строке нашёл по нужному названию, удалили старое значени, вставил новое.

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov обновил код для понимания, сначала собираем объект, при этом по любому селектору идёт перезапись автоматически, потом собираем строчку

Comment: Опять не то. Вы не поняли. Вот есть у меня готовая строчка из массива. И только потом я хочу поменять значение селекта который уже был выбран заранее. Тоесть изменение строки уже после её формирования.

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov что вы хотите я понял, но то что я предлагаю, и не только я, вам в коментариях уже отвечали, проще и красивее. Вам просто надо понять что я написал. Все проперти хранятся в объекте, а перед отправкой в GET запросе вы собираете результирующую строчку.

Comment: Нет, это совсем не то что мне нужно к сожалению

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov может быть тогда объясните что именно вам нужно в конечном итоге?

Comment: У вас есть скайп? Где можем обсудить конкретнее

Comment: Дмитрий всё получилось, спасибо!

Comment: @ElmanHuseynov Пожалуйста!